# How I can clean the header of a XML in java?

Tags: java, xml, header

I want clean the header of a XML  in JAVA like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document xmlns="xxxx" xmlns:xsi="yyyy" xsi:schemaLocation="zzzz">
...
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document>
...
```

I have a documentBuilder with the xml

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
org.w3c.dom.Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new  StringReader(strXmlContent)));
```

and now I dont know how I can do ti, any help??

Comment: Why? Both are perfectly legal. What do you care which form is taken?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
NodeList nodes = document.getChildNodes();
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    String id = nodes.item(i).getNodeValue();
    Element el = ((Attr) nodes.item(i)).getOwnerElement();
    el.removeAttribute(id);
}
```

To print it back:

```
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty( OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes" );
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult( new StringWriter() );
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource( document );
    transformer.transform( source, result );

    String xmlString = result.getWriter().toString();
    System.out.println( xmlString );
```

Comment: and how i can set de nodes into the document?